# Discord python bot: Is data sent through slash commands secure/protected?

Tags: python, security, discord, discord.py, data-protection

I am making a discord bot in python (using discord.py) and I was wondering if data sent through the slash commands is secured. I cannot find this anywhere online. For example, if I have a bot that connects to an outer service, can the user send their account name and password securely through a slash command? Or is the encryption of discord not enough for that?

**With secure/protected, I mean that it would be safe to transfer the users password through the command input towards the bot, with no possibility of it being intercepted or stored within discord.**

In my case, I want to set environment variables through my discord bot, but again, I'm afraid those secrets should not be given through slash commands.

Any idea if this is the case, and are there alternatives to sending sensitive data over discord commands? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question. I would say that since BOTs can actually store message history, it's not to be considered secure nor protected.

Comment: If you need a more secure way for sending sensitive data, I recommend you to use Modals instead of command parameters.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "secure/protected"?

Comment: Discord chats are not places to store sensitive secrets like passwords, and the fact you’re considering doing so is alarming and clearly shows whatever it is you’re trying to do is not a good fit as a Discord bot.

Comment: @Hazzu , does using a modal mean that the text (passwords in this case) can be sent without it being open for interception/somehow being stored in plain text?

Comment: @esqew , What are you talking about with "storing"? I am asking if discord slash commands (not chats), that only the user that called the command can see, are safe enough for the transfer of sensitive secrets towards the bot made for it. Nothing is meant to be stored in the discord chat itself.

Comment: @Davrozz Your message and command invocation data travels over the wire to Discord’s servers, where it can be stored (with or without your knowledge) for an indefinite period of time. If it wasn’t stored somewhere, how would it be possible for you to open your Discord client and see messages from others that were sent when your client wasn’t active? “Safe” is a completely arbitrary measure when we don’t know what the threat model looks like from which you’re attempting to defend this data. There is **never** any scenario where there is “*no possibility of [data] being intercepted or stored*”.

Comment: @esqew, Fair enough, I thought that since the slash commands are only visible to the user, and are then removed after for everyone, that it wasn't an actual "message" in that sense. But if you're saying that it *is* just a normal chat message, and that all contents of the input are saved on Discord's servers, then this will indeed never work. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Davrozz I can’t opine on if slash commands are treated similarly to messages or not, as I don’t know very much about Discord’s internals. However, the data *has* to exist somewhere on Discord’s side at some time for some period in order for them to provide their service to you, at which point you lose meaningful visibility into how that data is processed or retained. (1/2)

Comment: @Davrozz It is entirely possible (and has been the case with companies in the past) that there exists a plain text version of your slash command’s invocation somewhere on Discord’s infrastructure (in logs, an old database backup, in a RAM module of a physically insecure server…) which isn’t removed and is later exposed in a data breach or other incident. It’s up to you to decide whether or not these potential risks (among *many* possible other scenarios) are acceptable for you to use this mechanism as you plan to design it. (2/2)

Comment: @Davrozz Lastly, I don’t mean to be pedantic or blast a hole in your design for fun. When it comes to designing for security, these are the considerations we all should be making as engineers. Like I said, your implementation and how much you trust any intermediary provider is up to you. Just be mindful if you *do* actually need complete secrecy that using Discord or other opaque intermediary exposes you to risks that many would find unacceptable insofar as using it to transfer sensitive secrets.

Comment: @Davrozz
The reason for not using application command parameters is that the values ​​entered for the parameters are visible to everyone on the channel (just clink on the [slash command message](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/834546938366918667/1142160024404230355/image.png)).
I recommend that you get sensitive information through a [Modal](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/modals/basic.py), as data entered into Modal is not stored anywhere.

Comment: @esqew That makes sense. I'll not take the chances then, since it is just not designed for it. Even if it would have been pretty cool.